# Information about rabbitmq delayed-exchange

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

We are using rabbitmq-server_3.5.7 and its corresponding [delayed-message-exchange plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/)

Until now we were using direct-exchanges and controlling delays on message-producers on client applications (and also keeping track of the number of messages currently in the queue).

We have started using delay-exchanges successfully, but we are wondering how to check the number of messages that are currently delayed (this is, awaiting to get routed to a queue).

Does rabbit provide a way of knowing this? Is there any other method to access this information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, should've searched better before posting.

Basically, looking through closed issues in the repo:

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/issues/3

it's stated that this functionality will be available in release 3.7.0 (at the time of writing this it's still 3.6.6)